# Rotating text via the use of <p> & some CSS transforms, makes text wrap

Tags: html, css

I need to display text vertically in a `rowspan` within a table. The technique I'm using via `CSS` seems to "work", but the `width` of the `<p>` element can't be changed or else the text wraps to the next line and its not pretty.

Take a look at this jsfiddle I put together in order to replicate my issue.

http://jsfiddle.net/wn4ofcwx/

Any alternatives here? Or possible a fix to my current CSS.

> Note: Probably doesn't matter but I'm using the INK Framework (similar
>   to bootstrap).

Answer (score 0):

Actually I figured it out, it was as simple as using `white-space: nowrap;`

Which I completely forgot about!

http://jsfiddle.net/wn4ofcwx/7/

The text doesn't wrap because we are explicitly stating `nowrap`, you can re size the window to see how it keeps its position, now I can apply a width of just `10px` to take away all that excessive white space in the `rowspan`.

Answer (score -1):

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/wn4ofcwx/4/

What I added to the class `.rotate-vertical`:

```
  display: block;
  margin: auto auto;
  height: 17px;
```

And I took out : `Width: 50px;`

Cheers

---

Actually you can keep out the :  `display: block;`

The p element is already a display: block by default and you didn't overwrite it anywhere.

Comment: Yeah, but this is not fixing the problem. I had the `width` there to show that when you  lower it to like 30px. The text wraps. I want to have a low width and not take up all that space when the text is vertical. Not sure what your code is accomplishing here?

Comment: Well I took out the width and placed it in the centre of the <td>. 
By not taking up all that space... what space do you exactly mean? 

Do you want the grey box in which it is now, to be tight around it?

Comment: You're question is unclear! In my fiddle I have the text vertical without any width and not on two lines as you wanted. If you wanted to take out "all that excessive space", why didn't you mention it in your question?!